# Yii with generating and printing reports

Tags: php, yii

I am developing php web based application,in yii framework.
is there any open source  reporting tool which supports in yii framework?

Thanks

Comment: check these yii extensions [IReport](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/ireport) [HTML to PDF](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/pdf) [PDF Report generation using TCPDF ](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/tcpdf)

Comment: @marcovtwout:we need something like crystal report in php.

Answer (score 1):

**Yii** is a **PHP**-framework, and does not produce any report-able contents. I'm assuming you mean reporting tool for database-based reports. This all depends on how you structure your database, and it's not related to the framework you choose.

**Yii** does not require to follow a certain scheme when building your database, so you can choose whichever reporting tool you feel like using without worrying about any compatibility with Yii.

Answer (score 0):

This list of some extensions which can help you:

Charting with Yii:
1. Yii Open Flash Chart 2 Extension [feedback: very nice implementation and authors contribution - examples of using data from external sources(model, xml schema, etc.) would be greatly valuable]

1. Fusion Charts API Extension - Create and share Charts
2. Flot - EFlot plotting library encapsulation
3. Jqplot - extension of jqplot for charts
4. Cvisualizewidget - This widget makes it easy to render charts and graphs within your web application by utilising the visualize jQuery plugin.
5. Highcharts Extension

Printing, generating pdf, xls, cvs etc. with Yii:
1. Generating PDF with - tcpdf needs to be rechecked as it does not work properly...

1. Simple Yii extension printout for .datagrid and other .css elements printing - please offer your favourite extension usage methods
2. Yii CSV generator csvout See installation issues
3. Generating PDF with pdflib see topic
4. phpexcel-codeplex by sharehua
5. Print what you see - mprint by macinville